# google web Toolkit Validation Error

Tags: android, eclipse, gwt, android-c2dm

I have just installed gwt 2.4.0 google web toolkit for developing C2DM applications.
But the Eclipse Shows a problem **'Validating GWT Components(63%)'** and nothing happens afterwards.

How to solve this problem.Please help.